# NuGet.exe pack on build machine trying to hit nuget.org

Tags: tfs, nuget, tfsbuild

Trying to run NuGet.exe pack on a .csproj with a .nuspec file.

Everything works fine locally.  I've got NuGet.exe checked in alongside the sources.  This particular NuGet package does not have any dependencies on any other NuGet package listed in the .nuspec file (and even if it did, they would be available in source control).  I expected for NuGet.exe to just run on the build machine without trying to interact with anything on the web.

There is a NuGet.config file checked into the root folder of the source tree, but the command line commands run on the build machine appear to be ignoring it.  The version appears to be 2.6.40619.9041 (on my local machine, the same nuget.exe that is checked into version control).

On the build machine, it was initially failing with the "consent" error, below:

`Package restore is disabled by default. To give consent, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on Package Manager node and check 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.' You can also give consent by setting the environment variable 'EnableNuGetPackageRestore' to 'true'.`

This seemed odd because in this particular example, there are no packages to restore.  I'm trying to build a package that does not have any other package dependencies.  To get past this error, I started running it (in MSBuild Exec task) by forcing the EnableNuGetPackageRestore environment variable, like this:

`Command="(set EnableNuGetPackageRestore=true) & $(NuGetExe) pack $(NuGetSpecFile) $(NuGetPackArgs)"`

The next error from the build machine build log, after getting past the consent issue, is this:

`A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 168.62.224.25:443`

That IP address is the address for nuget.org.

It appears as though nuget.exe is trying to do something like auto-update itself or some other task.

Q1:  Is there any way to disable this behavior?  If it is the auto-update, can I prevent this with some sort of command line option.

Q2:  Although the nuget docs site lists -ConfigFile as a valid parameter for "nuget pack" it won't accept it.  Is that parameter supposed to work?

Q3:  If all else fails, how do I get NuGet.exe to look at our internal ProGet server (to which it could have access) instead of trying to look at nuget.org (to which access is blocked)?

Comment: You have set Nuget Package Restore to true.  This is the model where you do not check your packages into source control and Nuget.exe will download the packages you require at build time.  Read more about it here: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Comment: I replied above, showing the error I got when nugget.exe was run without setting the env var.  It fails either way, NuGet.exe doesn't run on this VM that does not have access to nuget.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm, I had checked in the NuGet.exe "bootstrapper" instead of the actual program.

Once I checked in the version found at %LOCALAPPDATA%\NuGet it stopped trying to reach out to the web.